# How to use an android library (.aar file) in Ionic with Capacitor

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, aar

I need to use a library from an android device, that was passed to me in an aar file, in a project with Ionic and I can't integrate it. Searching all I find is that it should make a Cordova plugin but I am using Capacitor.

I need to be able to integrate it into the project and use it with typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same problem, what I did was create a Capacitor plugin using the command `npm init @capacitor/plugin`.

The issue was that there was an error when including the `.aar` library within the plugin, as it compiles as an `.aar` library on its own.

You have to place the `.aar` library inside `/android/libs` of both the plugin and the project, and in the plugin's `build.gradle` file, add it as `compileOnly files('libs/[lib_name].aar')` instead of an `implementation`.